# Setting proper Constraints to UIView in Portrait and Landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout, constraints

This is the first time I'm making an iOS app in both orientations.

I have a UIView placed like in above image.[image: 1]]

I have set the following constraints: Horizontally Centered, Vertically Centered, Leading and Trailing Space : 8, Height : 265.

I want this UIView to look fullscreen in landscape mode such that Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom is stuck to all edges.

Please help me in doing it. The above set constraints are not looking proper in landscape. See image below :

[image]

The above screenshots are of iPhone 6s size. I need app to support iPad in both orientations too.

These are the constraints already applied by me :

[image]

EDIT : After vary for traits is applied :

[image]

Portrait constraints are the active one and greyed out ones are applied to landscape. It looks as I want in storyboard but still taking height of portrait during runtime.

EDIT 2: Vary for traits is working on that particular size class but not on all size classes. Please suggest how to set same constraints on all size classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

select landscape option (below the screen near to setting auto layout pane) then press vary for traits , now give new constraints that you want in landscape mode then select done varying.

Now you have two different constraints for landscape and portrait mode.

Comment: I tried that but it only shows fine in storyboard and not in simulator. Constraints have been set properly

Comment: It is working fine for me. will you show me by images or video??

Comment: what you select when applying vary for trait. you have to select both height and width

Comment: R u checking in which device??

Comment: no you have to set for different size classes .e.g for iphone 7 plus you have to define different constraints.

Comment: Is there any way to set it the same to all devices landscape modes

Comment: May be not beause iphone 7 plus and other iphone device have different compact width and height.ANd you have to set size classes according to compact/regular height/width

Comment: Ok.. So I finally understood the catch there! How many size classes are there? In short, how many times must this process be repeated to support all iPhones and iPads?

Comment: Actually i dont remember all but it may be 9 different modes for different conditions. So you can choose among them as per your need.

Comment: How is possible I've never seen this options before? Thanks mate!!

Answer (score 2):

Add below constraints just change the value of constant according to your requirement -

[image]

Check below -

[image]

Comment: For that I will have to make outlets of all constraints?

Comment: these are trailing, leading, height and vertically center constraints.

Comment: @Dia -  got it ??

Comment: If I put leading trailing top and bottom to say 8 or 16 then that will not look as expected in portrait

Comment: what is you requirement please share screen shot.

Comment: I want the UIView to look the same as in portrait screenshot but stuck to all edges in landscape mode

Comment: I tried. But how will it give me required result in all screen sizes when height is fixed

Comment: if you don't want to fix height then remove it and add top and bottom contraints.

Comment: top and bottom is varying for both orientations